# Why do we need SocketOptions.SO_BROADCAST to enable broadcast?

Tags: sockets

If we want to broadcast information from a socket, we need to enable `SocketOptions.SO_BROADCAST`. However, I don't understand why that is necessary.

My understanding is we set the packet with a broadcast address, just the same way as set a unicast address. Then we just need to send it through a regular socket. If its a UDP socket, then a UDP header will be added to that packet, and then an IP header containing the receiver's IP address (in this case is the broadcast address in the form of `192.168.255.255`), and then a MAC address `(FF:FF:FF:FF)` is added.

I think the router will get the packet and perform the broadcast. I don't understand why we need to set the socket attribute to `SO_BROADCAST`.

Comment: In most cases these calls just call the same thing in the OS.  This is likely to be a restriction of your OS, not Java.

Comment: You should put that as an answer @PeterLawrey

Answer (score 30, accepted):

"Socket semantics require that an application set the SO_BROADCAST option on before attempting to send a datagram to a base or broadcast address. This protects the application from accidentally sending a datagram to many systems."

[Source](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.halz002/security_tcpip_resrcs_so_broadcast.htm)

Comment: thanks a lot. I guess this applies to linux and windows as well

Comment: source link is broken :(

Comment: I've fixed it now.

Answer (score 3):

In most cases these calls just call the same thing in the OS. This is likely to be a restriction of your OS, not Java.

Comment: ok, but a further question is why does linux need to do that? the same thing seems to be used in windows as well

Answer (score 1):

To complement Jeremy Friesner's answer, here is a good wording I found about this: https://notes.shichao.io/unp/ch7/

> Since an application must set this socket option before sending a broadcast datagram, it prevents a process from sending a broadcast when the application was never designed to broadcast. For example, a UDP application might take the destination IP address as a command-line argument, but the application never intended for a user to type in a broadcast address. Rather than forcing the application to try to determine if a given address is a broadcast address or not, the test is in the kernel: If the destination address is a broadcast address and this socket option is not set, EACCES is returned.

In other words, by setting this option, the **application** is saying that it is designed to support the broadcast use-case and is ready to handle broadcast IP addresses provided by **user**.

Since not all apps were designed for broadcast, the option is disable by default.