# using setsockopt() for config Connections

Tags: python-3.x, idl-programming-language, programmers-notepad

How we can work with setsockopt and it constants for configure our connection  for example:

```
socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,SO_BROADCAST,1)
```

what does `SOL_SOCKET` and `SO_BROADCAST`  in code above?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21515946/sol-socket-in-getsockopt

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16217958/why-do-we-need-socketoptions-so-broadcast-to-enable-broadcast