# Whats does it mean for a client\server to broadcast?

Tags: c, sockets, networking, udp, broadcast

I'm reading "Bjee's Guide to Network Programming Using Internet Sockets" and I'm trying to understand what's the meaning of "Broadcasting" (let's say, of a client). Does it means that the client sends packets to everyone connected to the local network? If so, can we send packet only to a set of connections on this network?
I know that there's this "Broadcast address" thing, but I'm having difficulties to understand why do we need it, if we'll send the broadcast to anyone on the local network anyway?

Here's the code example from his book, re-written by me (see chapter "6.5. Broadcast Packets-Hello,World!"):

```
#define SERVERPORT 4950
#define SERVERIP "192.168.1.1" /* should it be 255.255.255.255 ? */


int main()
{
    int sockfd;
    int broadcast = 1;    
    struct sockaddr_in their_addr;
    char buf[] = "This is the client's buffer";

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

    setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, &broadcast,
                                         sizeof(broadcast));

    their_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    their_addr.sin_port = htons(SERVERPORT);
    inet_aton(SERVER_IP ,&their_addr.sin_addr);
    memset(&(their_addr.sin_zero), 0, 8));

    sendto(sockfd, buf, strlen(buf), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&their_addr,
                                               sizeof(struct sockaddr));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16217958/why-do-we-need-socketoptions-so-broadcast-to-enable-broadcast).

Comment: This wiki also explains a bit about [multicast/broadcast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_multicast).

Comment: @TedLyngmo This is good, though I still don't get it how can I simultaneously send packet to all users on local network and at the same time address it to a specific hosts. maybe I look at it the wrong way?

Comment: @LiorNachmias It sounds like you want multicast. The clients will then subscribe to messages sent to the specific multicast address and you can send one message that (potentially) reaches all subscribers.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Ok, I think that I'm starting to get it. In that case, let's assume that a host on a local network that hasn't been subscribed to anything (beside being connected to that network), and another host on the same network broadcast to all (not multicast), will the unsubscribed host still get the packet?

Comment: It will be seen by all network cards in that subnet for sure but a client application would still need to listen to be able to pick it up.